# Socket TCP C# more data than buffer

Tags: c#, sockets, loops, tcp

**What I achieve to do**
I have a server sending data back to the client. The client reads data from the buffer, concatenates it an deserializes it into an object of a certain type.

**The Problem**
Now sometimes it happens that the loop for receiving data exits before all data is received so the data I want to deserialize is incomplete. I assume this happens, because the client processes the data too quickly. The client wants to process more data but there's none available.
This happens, when the data sent is more than the buffer can hold. The original idea was to read chunks and concatenate them but this does not always work completely.

**The Idea**
Is there a way to tell the client how much data should be received, so I can amend the loop and have all data received, before it is processed?

This is how my receive method basically looks like:

```
private void receiveData()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int bytesReceived;

    // list that gathers all data from all chunks
    List<byte> totalData = new List<byte>();

    do
    {
         // receive one chunk of data
         bytesReceived = clientSocket.Receive(data);

         // copying all bytes received to a byteArray of the exact size
         byte[] dataExtracted = new byte[bytesReceived];
         Array.Copy(data, dataExtracted, bytesReceived);

         // Add the byteArray to the total data received
         totalData.AddRange(dataExtracted);
    } while (clientSocket.Available > 0);

    // Do something with totalData received
}
```

I am looking for a way to receive all data, before I process it, but I am not sure how to do the loop or better how to set the conditions here. Any help or links to investigate more are appreciated.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806007/sending-some-constraints-to-client-from-server-in-c-sharp/

Comment: basically sender must first send data length and then the data to the client

Comment: Can you help me find the point in the duplicate that tells me how to send the length of the data first? I can easily read all data that is stored in the array byte[] but sometimes get problems, when there will be several chunks (each of the size data.length which is only the length of that one array already received). I mean, is it possible to send something like a header?

Comment: Yes why not? Just send first length. Then data. Here is also similar question I answered recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297216/c-sharp-socket-receive-byte-array-length/34297612#34297612, if something is still unclear let me know. The info is there also in the dupe I believe, just you need bit more reading.

Comment: OK, I get it. So the clue is to have a fixed number of bytes to be sent in advance (or in the beginning of each stream). I read those bytes and know how much will follow (in one or more chunks) and can make my loop read incoming data until the full length is received - correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that' right

Comment: Thanks a lot! That has been a very helpful lesson!